# Sending logs to DataDog using a Serilog sink not working

Tags: c#, serilog, datadog

**Context:**

- Having looked over numerous answers and documentation. I am having to resort to asking others and I am thankful for your help.

  - C# configuration: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/csharp/?tab=serilog
  - Support EU endpoints (My DataDog is on an eu server): https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=host#supported-endpoints
  - Github documentation for Serilog: https://github.com/DataDog/serilog-sinks-datadog-logs

**My set up:**

- I have a DataDog trial account

  [image]
- I have a DataDog agent installed locally but I actually want to send logs to DataDog with an agentless approach

  [image]
- My logger makes logs into my Log/log.json files although It doesn't seem to update the file immediatley and can take several minutes to finally place the information into the file (no idea why)

  [image]
- I have the following dependencies installed as per the serilog documentation:

  [image]
- I have a .Net 6 project for an Angular App.

  [image]
- I have an appsettings.json that looks like this:

  ```
    {
        "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "SitePageToSitePageModernConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Blah;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
        },
        "Serilog": {
            "Using": [
                "Serilog.Sinks.File",
                "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs"
            ],
            "MinimumLevel": {
                "Default": "Error",
                "Override": {
                    "Microsoft": "Error",
                    "System": "Error",
                    "My.App.Namespace.Something": "Information"
                }
            },
            "WriteTo": [
                {
                    "Name": "File",
                    "Args": {
                        "path": "Logs/log.json",
                        "rollingInterval": "Day", // When a new file is created
                        "flushToDiskInterval": "00:00:01", // Currently does nothing. seems to be overwritten by operating system's paging cache interval (whatever that is)
                        "retainedFileCountLimit": 7 // How many files should be retained over the days specified by rollingInterval
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Name": "DatadogLogs",
                    "Args": {
                        "apiKey": "d7...b07",
                        "source": "something",
                        "host": "noideawhatgoeshere",
                        "configuration": {
                            "Url": "http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Enrich": [
                "FromLogContext",
                "WithMachineName",
                "WithThreadId"
            ],
            "Properties": {
                "Application": "MyApplicationSample"
            }
        }
    }
  ```
- I am setting up the Serilog in the following manner:

  ```
    // WebApplicationBuilder builder...

    builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        ConfigurationManager configurationManager = builder.Configuration;
        Logger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom
            .Configuration(configurationManager)
            .CreateLogger();

        // Adds serilog to the logging providers
        loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
    });
  ```

In a controller, I am using `ILogger<MySiteController>` to log.

```
    // constructor injects: 
    ...ILogger<MySiteController> _logger...

    // call to controller runs some logs:

    logger.LogInformation("Test information");
    logger.LogError("Test error");
    logger.LogWarning("Test warning");
```

**My question/problem:**

1. None of my logs end up in DataDog. Any ideas what I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL configured, in this case, was incorrect and should have been:

```json
"configuration": {
     "url": "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu",
     "port": 443
}
```

For more information, I have laid out some comments to help others in the future:

```json
{
    // ...
    //"AllowedHosts": "*",
    // ...

    // Serilog framework can look at this to configure itself
    "Serilog": {

        // This determines which of the types of logging you want to have
        "Using": [

            // This is for logging into a file in a static manner
            "Serilog.Sinks.File",

            // This is for logging into a file that can be configured to log for a day and then create a new file at the next day (a rolling file, get it?)
            "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile",

            // This will allow logs to go into your console. Console in this case (for an Angular driven app, means the Terminal that appears when you launch your app)
            "Serilog.Sinks.Console",

            // This will allow logging to Datadog
            "Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs"
        ],

        // These are the log levels you want to support
        "MinimumLevel": {

            // By default, you could say "I only want to see errors coming up"
            "Default": "Error",

            // If you are wanting to see information or debug or trace etc logs from other specific c# class namespaces, then you can configure them here
            "Override": {

                // Anything in a namespace that starts with `Microsoft` we only care about Errors being flagged (for example)
                "Microsoft": "Error",

                // Anything in a namespace that starts with `System` we only care about Errors being flagged (for example)
                "System": "Error",

                // If you had a tool with a C# class's namespace of "My.Tooling.Test", you, in this case will probably want to see all the logs you raise. so we could set this to Information (for example)
                "My.Tooling.Test": "Information"
            }
        },

        // Given that we have defined which frameworks we want to make use of in the "Using" section, we can now use the framework functionality for Console, File, RollingFile, Datadog, etc.
        "WriteTo": [

            // Tells Serilog to log stuff to the console
            {
                "Name": "Console"
                //... You can configure more here but you'll need to Google that yourself
            },

            // Tells Serilog to log stuff to a File
            {
                "Name": "File",

                //... You can configure more here but you'll need to Google that yourself
                "Args": {
                    "path": "App_Data\\logs\\log.txt",
                    "rollingInterval": 3,
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} [P{ProcessId}/D%APP_DOMAIN_ID%/T{ThreadId}] {Level:u4} {CorrelationId} {UserId} - {Message:lj}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
            },

            // Tells Serilog to log stuff to a Rolling File
            {
                "Name": "RollingFile",

                //... You can configure more here but you'll need to Google that yourself.
                "Args": {
                    "path": "App_Data\\logs\\DiagnosticTraceLog.txt{RollingDate}",
                    "shared": true,
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff} [P{ProcessId}/D%APP_DOMAIN_ID%/T{ThreadId}] {Level:u4} {CorrelationId} {UserId} - {Message:lj}{Exception}{NewLine}"
                }
            },

            // Tells Serilog to log stuff to a DataDog instance
            {
                // This name is important! It must be precisely this to work!
                "Name": "DatadogLogs",

                // The configuration properties here must all be written precisely as the following are
                "Args": {

                    // Mandatory | API Key - Found in Datadog Organization/Api Keys section.
                    "apiKey": "6c...91",

                    // Optional | An arbitrary "source" that enables you to filter to your logs within the DataDog application
                    "source": "anything.you.want",

                    // Optional | An arbitrary "servive" that enables you to filter to your logs within the DataDog application
                    "service": "anything.you.want",

                    // Optional | An arbitrary "host" that enables you to filter to your logs within the DataDog application
                    "host": "anything.you.want",

                    // Optional | Arbitrary "tags" that enables you to filter to your logs within the DataDog application
                    "tags": [ "app.name:My.Tooling.Test" ],

                    // Optional | The default Datadog server is "intake.logs.datadoghq.com". If your DataDog instance is on the "app.datadoghq.com" URL, you do not need any of this configuration.
                    //
                    //          | If you are not on the default Datadog server, you will need to find out what server you are on by visiting here and using the dropdown at the right https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/site/
                    //          | and then, once you know the server, you can visit here for the URL to use: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=host#supported-endpoints
                    // 
                    //          | IMPORTANT: the URLs are not quite the entire URL that's needed. Be aware that "https://" will need to be placed on to determine which type you want to use. For example:
                    "configuration": {
                        "url": "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu",
                        "port": 443
                    }
                }
            }
        ],

        // This ends up being stored in the final log message that is raised for you. You'll see it in DataDog under "properties" object where it mentions "Thread Id" or "SourceContext" for example.
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],

        // This ends up being stored in the final log message that is raised for you. You'll see it in DataDog under "properties" object where it mentions "Application".
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "My.Tooling.Test"
        }
    }
}
```

And specifically for c# apps, the following packages are required to be installed to use the above `appsettings.json`:

- Mandatory stuff:

  - microsoft.extensions.configuration.json
  - serilog.aspnetcore
- Sink types (The usings defined in appsettings.json):

  - serilog.sinks.datadog.logs
  - serilog.sinks.file
  - serilog.sinks.rollingfile
- Enrichers that you've used:

  - serilog.enrichers.environment
  - serilog.enrichers.thread
  - serilog.settings.configuration
  - serilog.aspnetcore.enrichers.correlationid

Which can all be configured in C# like so (You have 2 choices):

```cs
// This allows you to add a Logging Provider to the already filled out list of logging providers
// that are supplied by default to your application.
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    // Get the builder's configuration from your Program 
    // (It essentially just gets the appsettings.json file)
    ConfigurationManager configurationManager = builder.Configuration;

    // Create a new LoggerConfiguration so that you can tell 
    // it to get its configuration from your appsettings.json file
    Logger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom
        .Configuration(configurationManager)

        // Finally create the logger which will be used
        .CreateLogger();

    // Adds serilog to the logging providers
    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
});
```

OR

```cs
// Forces all logs to go through your single serilog configuration
// Be aware that if you use this, you need to ensure you configure your Serilog to
// do Console logging, otherwise you won't see any logs in the console.
// Luckily, I've provided all the code you need to do that in the appsettings.json configuration
// (But you may need to change the log level to Information or Debug for it to show up)
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
   loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
});
```

And you can finally create logs by injecting the `ILogger<YOURCLASSNAME> logger` into the class where you want to use it and running the following commands:

```cs
logger.LogInformation("{message}", "Test");
logger.LogWarning("{message}", "Test");
logger.LogError("{message} {exception}", "Test", error);
logger.LogWarning(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Something() { Name = "Something", Description = "Something" }));
```